# ereg_replaceとmb_ereg_replaceの仕様的な違い

Tags: php, 正規表現

公式では`ereg_replace`は「PHP 5.3.0 で 非推奨」と書いてありますが、`mb_ereg_replace`にはそのような記述がありません。
名前からすると`ereg_replace`も`mb_ereg_replace`も同じ仕組みを使っているように思うのですが、全く別物なのでしょうか。

ereg_replace
http://php.net/manual/ja/function.ereg-replace.php

mb_ereg_replace
http://php.net/manual/ja/function.mb-ereg-replace.php

`mb_ereg_replace`をつかうメリットがなければ`preg_replace`で統一したいなぁ(´・ω・`)

Answer (score 3):

mb_ereg系ではRubyと同じく鬼車を使うので、ereg系・preg系どちらとも別物のようです。

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Kenji_s/20130221/php_regexp
http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~wv7y-kmr/memo/php_mbstring.html#mb_regex

preg系ではUTF-8以外のMBCSを扱えないというのが分かりやすい制約だとは思いますが、入出力で変換する方法が採れるなら問題にはなりませんね。